# .cab file not being created when building project using ISCmdBld.exe

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I am using InstallShield to build my project's ism file. Though when I am building the ism, after opening it in InstallShield, it's working fine, but when I try to build it through the command, the resultant MSI file is not build correctly and its size is reduced to almost half.

Also, when I investigated the logs, I came to know that Data1.cab file is not being created when building through the command line.

The command I use to build is the following:

> ISCmdBld.exe -p project.ism -r "Release 1"

Can somebody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest passing both the product configuration (-a) and release (-r).  Note that InstallShield won't give you an error message if you capitalize or spell it wrong.  It'll just create a release by that name with all the default settings and build it. (Yes... #FAIL I know. It's been that way for years.)

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your reply. We had tried like "ISCmdBld.exe -p project.ism -r "Release 1 -c comp" but the behaviour is still in consistent. Even with -a options the result is same.